# How making the CommentBox Moderation work properly?

Tags: facebook, plugins

Since 2 weeks I am stuck with the social plugin commentbox. I managed to install the "Hike - Free Tab Builder" on my FB Fanpage and inserted there a HTML code with text and I also included a cuple of boxes there. In order to moderate those boxes I made an App (commentbox) to get an AppID and I did everything asked in the fb.developers tutorial. I put the asked IDs as meta command in the "head" section and put anything else right behind the "body" tag.

It never manages to get connected to the Moderation Tool and I cannot say whats wrong. I am working on this for 2 weeks now, I asked and searched around for answers but without succes. Maybe anyone here can give the answer.

Here is some part of the code I wrote:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>

  <meta property="fb:admins" content="{10000113xxxxxxx}"/>
  <meta property="fb:app_id" content="{20368994xxxxxxx}"/>

    <title>Research</title>


<style type="text/css">

    P {font-family: arial; color: rgb(0, 0, 102); font-size: 1}
    H2 {font-family: arial; font-size: 4; color: rgb(153, 0, 0); font: bold}
    H3 {font-family: arial; font-size: 3; color: rgb(153, 0, 0); font: bold}
    HR {font-family: arial; width: auto}

</style>

</head>

<body>
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId      : '203689xxxxxxx', // App ID
      channelUrl : '//channel.html', // Channel File
      status     : true, // check login status
      cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
      xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
    });

    // Additional initialization code here
  };

  // Load the SDK Asynchronously
  (function(d){
     var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
     ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
   }(document));
</script>

 <div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/de_DE/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=2036899xxxxxxx";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

<h2>Contents</h2>

(...)

<div class="fb-comments" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/(...)/app_151503908244383" data-num-posts="10" data-width="785"></div>

(...)
</body>
</html>
```

Any idea whats wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

you have to define og:url, og:title and og:img.

http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug is helpfull tool. Just write your url and let it say something to you.